# datagridview with combobox not displaying data when bound to a Datatable

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, combobox

I have a Datatable that is bound to a `DataGridView`.The `DataGridView` gives me the required information retrieved from the `DataTable`. One of the columns needs to be as a `ComboBox`. How to I make sure that the information is displayed from the Datatable with one column being a `ComboBox`?

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)

[Here is another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) on Template Fields from MSDN.